# Writing Html file with java duplicates the entry

Tags: java, html, file

I have a program to do some calculations in excel and writing the output in a table tag in html file. I am adding rows dynamically at runtime depending on the number of results. While writing to html file the entries are not correct.
Suppose i have 50 rows in a html file. I am appening  49 rows at runtime in the template file and replacing values $id0, $age0, $time0.....$id49, $age49, $time49 in html file . For me first 10 rows are writing properly. From 11th row, the values are writing wrong. I am getting correct ones in the logs as well.

```
for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
  htmlString = htmlString.replace("$id"+i, cycle.get("id"+i).toString().trim());
  htmlString = htmlString.replace("$time"+i, cycle.get("time"+i).toString().trim());
  htmlString = htmlString.replace("$name"+i, cycle.get("name"+i).toString().trim())
}
```

The entry comes in html as

> id  Name   age   time
>   9   abc     8     8.08
>   10  xyz    12     9.19
>   11  xyz1   121    9.191
>   12  xyz12  122    9.192

the values for id 11, 12 are wrong. It shows 10th id's values appended with 1,2 etc.

Comment: if you use `replace` then your results will be screwed - consider your are replacing `id1` with `xxx`, this will be OK if you only have `id1`, but if your have `id10` `id11` etc, then you will end up with `xxx0` and `xxx1` when all you wanted to replace was `id1`

Comment: Not sure why you are replacing values in a HTML file - consider using JSP

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to replace by if there is a white space after the `id` you could replace `'id1 '` with `'xx1 '` or use replaceAll and some regex

Comment: I will be computing some data from excel and those values I am replcaing in these.  id1 =1, Name=abc, age=10 etc. No whitespace after those variables.

Comment: OK, no white space but you have a comma you could replace 'id1,' with 'xx1,'

Comment: Sorry i could not understand why there is a whitespace or comma ? $id11 should replace with value in my map(For example : id11 value may be 231 in the map).

Comment: But when you replaced `$id1` with `xxx` you also replaced `$id11` and it is now `xxx1` - if you replace `$id1,` with `xxx,` then `$id11` will not be updated

Comment: @ScaryWombat : Thank you man. You saved my day. I added : after the $id11 like $id11: and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by adding an extra character after the $id1 like $id1:. 
Example:
id1=abc
id2=xyz
without the extra code $id11 was giving as abc1